# Strange characters when typing left arrow keys on the bluetooth keyboard

Tags: mac, keyboard, bluetooth

My Bluetooth keyboard now has three keys malfunctional.

If I hit the left key multiple times it produces this:

> ‘u7’jm;mujmu7;jmm;m;jm;’’jm’7jm;;ju7jmu;jmu;;’’’7’’’;’;’’’’’;’’;’’jmu;’7;’’’’‘m;’

If I hit right keys it produces this:

> \lo.l\..l..lo9.l\lo..lo.llo9lo.o\.9.\

If I hit the tilde key it gives me:

> swx2      `swx       `         x              `x `w2

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have a spare, wired, keyboard to see if the problem is still there with a different keyboard?

Comment: My other bluetooth keyboard and my laptop's built-in keyboard are both working well. I will try a wired keyboard later

Comment: If you have two *working* keyboards it is likely that the BT keyboard in question is broken.